# How can I map "Shift + (A number)" to "(Another number)" using xmodmap?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, remapping, xmodmap

I want to map my keys so that pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> produces a <kbd>6</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>produces a <kbd>7</kbd>, etc. to make it possible to type all numbers using only my left hand.

When I try `xmodmap -e "keycode 10 Shift_L = 6"`, I get a <kbd>6</kbd> when I press <kbd>1</kbd>, but that happens even when I don't have Shift depressed.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out:

```
keycode 10 = 1 6
keycode 11 = 2 7
...
keycode 14 = 5 0
```